# CSVToTable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, import-from-csv

I am currently using this plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/, but for some reason can't convert my CSV to a html table. I followed the documentation provided, but it just sticks on "Loading CSV Data...", can someone help me out please?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
          $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('data.csv');
        });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="CSVTable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/blah/Desktop/test/data.csv. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: i believe its because its not on a webserver, any chance anyone can provide a csv web doc for me please, that i can reference to and use as an example

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a working exameple : https://github.com/medialab/reanalyse/tree/master/static/js/csvtotable, a test csv and a test template.

You can follow that example which is using table sorter too.

Your code after you download the folder will be this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery CSVToTable</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/csvtable.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $.get('test.csv', function(data) {
            $('#CSVSource').html('<pre>' + data + '</pre>');
        });
        $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('test.csv', { loadingImage: 'images/loading.gif', startLine: 0 });
        $.get('test.tsv', function(data) {
            $('#TSVSource').html('<pre>' + data + '</pre>');
        });
        $('#TSVTable').CSVToTable('test.tsv', { loadingText: 'Loading TSV Data...', loadingImage: 'images/loading.gif', startLine: 0, separator: "\t" });
        $('#CSVTable2').CSVToTable('test.csv', { loadingImage: 'images/loading.gif', startLine: 1, headers: ['Album Title', 'Artist Name', 'Price ($USD)'] }).bind("loadComplete",function() { 
            $('#CSVTable2').find('TABLE').tablesorter();
        });;
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

This is a test of the CSVToTable plugin.
<br><br>
Original CSV (comma separated values) source of <a href="test.csv">test.csv</a>:<br>
<div id="CSVSource" class="source">
</div>

<br><br>
CSV To Table:<br>
<div id="CSVTable">

</div>

<br><br>
Original TSV (tab separated values) source of <a href="test.tsv">test.tsv</a>:<br>
<div id="TSVSource" class="source">
</div>

<br><br>
TSV To Table:<br>
<div id="TSVTable">

</div>


<br><br>
CSV To Table - made sortable using <a target="_blank" href="http://tablesorter.com/">jQuery tablesorter:</a><br>
<div id="CSVTable2">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

You can use your own jQuery version.

Comment: It works fine for me but one more additional feature request, how can we create href for data?

Column1 Column2
data    data

to something like:

data    <a href="http:www" + data>data</data>